# inserting variable attribute in notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A rails 4 controller action, defined as a collection in routes, has:

```
@user_last = User.where('id = ?', params[:dayprofile][:id]).pluck("last_name")
respond_to do |format|
  if @dayprofile.update(dayprofile_params)
    format.html { redirect_to now_dayprofiles_path, notice: 'Status updated for #{@user_last}' }
  end
end
```

However the rendering is textually coming out as `#{@user_last}`.  What and why is this syntax inappropriate in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes:

```
notice: "Status updated for #{@user_last}"
```

Comment: This works properly.  Is this a Ruby convention (if you have a proper reference for distinguishing use-cases that would be great!) ?  If so, then why does Rails scaffolding generate the notices with single quotes?

Comment: This method is called “string interpolation”. When you need to use it you must use double quotes or '+', for example `'Status updated for ' + @user_last`. By default rails generates notices with single quotes because they did not use interpolation there. You can learn more about it [here](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html)

Comment: Great! The reference is appreciated; I've literally surfed with my rails use without ever encountering this issue.